# Does traffic to weird subdomains on my LAN indicate a security issue?

Tags: security, subdomain, router, lan, opendns

I am a user of OpenDNS, and I am noticing network traffic to weird subdomains on my local area network. Suppose the "Local Domain Name" setting on my router is named "mynetwork". I am seeing many requests to domains like:

```
lb._dns-sd._udp.mynetwork
db._dns-sd._udp.mynetwork
b._dns-sd._udp.mynetwork
tvovhvumfcuvo.mynetwork
pqwakwyids.mynetwork
vbqulcywazgwao.mynetwork
wjyuspdzzbac.mynetwork
etc.
```

If this is not normal traffic how should I discern where my problem lies? Should I install something like "Little Snitch" on my Macs for example?

Comment: I am also noticing that every day the domains change and there are exactly 18 requests to each domain.

Comment: Are you using a mac?

Comment: Yes I have two Macs on the local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out [this](https://docs.menandmice.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6360942) answer from menandmice, where they say:

> These are queries generated by 'Multicast/Unicast DNS Service Discovery or 
>   Zeroconf', which is a service of Apple 'Bonjour/Rendevous' or Unix Services like 
>   'Avahi'. DNS Queries coming from Port 5353 are DNS queries from a Zeroconf service.
>
> The DNS Service Discovery enabled clients are looking for pointers to services running in their network block 192.0.2.0/24.
>
> This is harmless. If there is not PTR record for the requested ownernames, it 
>   only means that unicast Zeroconf is not configured.

"unicast Zeroconf is not configured" might not be **your** exact problem, but overall it's **nothing to worry about**.